# Can you use System Intrusion on the Original Enterprise in Star Trek Bridge Crew (VR)?

Tags: star-trek-bridge-crew

In Star Trek Bridge Crew, the USS Aegis has a System Intrusion feature that hacks enemy vessels. On the Aegis, anyone but the captain can use it. Does it exist on the Original Enterprise?

Parts are there: Tactical can scan and some details show up on the right wall. But I haven't found the hacking option at any station.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, System Intrusion is not available on the *Original Enterprise*.**

You can confirm this by activating the help overlay while playing the game (<kbd>F1</kbd> on Keyboard/Mouse). The help overlay will show you what each of the unlabeled buttons does on the *Original Enterprise* bridge. While the engineering station has the teleporter controls (which were on the other half of the Systems Intrusion display on the *Aegis*), System Intrusion is not present on any of the stations.

[Other players on Reddit have noted the lack of System Intrusion on the *Original Enterprise*](https://www.reddit.com/r/BridgeCrew/comments/6wzvud/new_stbc_player_differences_between_aegis_and/).